# cloudera CDH5 install error

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to install CDH5 on centOS. My cloudera downloads is at at/home/cloudera/Downloads. 
But when I follow the instruction, I got this error. Could anyone help?

```
root@localhost ~]# sudo yum --nogpgcheck localinstall cloudera-cdh-5-0.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Local Package Process
Cannot open: cloudera-cdh-5-0.x86_64.rpm. Skipping.
Nothing to do
```

Comment: Are you sure it downloaded completely? Check the file size against the file size in the repository you downloaded it from.

Comment: @JeremyBeard: I just checked, I think its download completely.

Answer (score 1):

1. cd /home/cloudera/Downloads
2. chmod +x
3. sudo yum --nogpgcheck localinstall cloudera-cdh-5-0.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 0):

rpm's path is missing in yum localinstall, try use the full path or cd to download folder first and try again:

```
cd Your_Download_Folder
sudo yum --nogpgcheck localinstall cloudera-cdh-5-0.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

First check permission on the .rpm file
ls -l
give permission with following command
chmod +x  cloudera-cdh-5-0.x86_64.rpm
then execute following command.
sudo yum --nogpgcheck localinstall cloudera-cdh-5-0.x86_64.rpm

I hope it will help you :)